# Example of a sequence of functions that converges pointwise to 0

Tags: real-analysis

Prove or give a counterexample.

Let $\lbrace f_n (x)\rbrace$ be a sequence of functions that converge pointwise to 0 for every $x$ in a closed interval [a,b]. Then, for every sequence $\lbrace x_{n}\rbrace$ in [a,b], $lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n} (x_{n}) = 0$.

My intuition says this is true so I'm going for a proof.

We know that $\lbrace f_n (x)\rbrace$ converges pointwise, this means if we fix a point $x_0$ in the interval, $lim_{n \to \infty} \lbrace f_n (x_0)\rbrace = 0$ for all $x_0 \in [a,b]$. By definition, given an $\epsilon > 0$, for every $x_0$ in [a,b] there exists a $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n > N_0$ then $f_{n}(x_{0}) < \epsilon$.

I would have loved to take $N = max \lbrace N_i \rbrace$ but there are an infinitely many of them so no go here.

Consider $n > N_0$, we have $\vert f_n(x_n) \vert \leq \vert f_n(x_n) - f_n(x_0) \vert + \vert f_n(x_0) \vert$, we know the second term is less than $\epsilon$ but there is a problem with the first. What if $f_n$ is not continuous?

So I figured if there were a counterexample it would be some discontinuous function. Problem is I can't imagine how. Since whatever the function is, by hypothesis eventually everywhere would tend to 0.

Comment: Let $f_n$ have graph consisting of the straight line segments connecting $(0,0), (1/n,1), (1/(n-1),0)$, and $(1,0)$. Looks like /\\____

Comment: Thanks @David Mitra, I see it. The sequence is $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Can you relate this condition to *uniform* convergence?  In other words, since the condition is stronger than pointwise convergence, characterize it.